# print only characters after the delimiter python

Tags: python

I have this simple python programme:

```
import csv

f = open('comp.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f: 
    string = row[2]
    array = string.split(":")
    for word in array:
        print(word)

f.close()
```

my data looks like this:

```
,Organization,Score 1,Score 2
,Snap Election,"Overall evaluation: 3
Invite to interview: 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 4
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 4
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 3
Use or provision of open data (1): 4
Use or provision of open data (2): 4
""Open by default"" (1): 4
""Open by default"" (2): 3
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 4
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 3
Market opportunity and timing (1): 4
Market opportunity and timing (2): 4
Triple bottom line impact (1): 3
Triple bottom line impact (2): 4
Triple bottom line impact (3): 3
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 4
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 3
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 1
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 4
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 4","Overall evaluation: 3
Invite to interview: 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 4
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 4
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 3
Use or provision of open data (1): 3
Use or provision of open data (2): 4
""Open by default"" (1): 3
""Open by default"" (2): 2
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 3
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 4
Market opportunity and timing (1): 3
Market opportunity and timing (2): 2
Triple bottom line impact (1): 3
Triple bottom line impact (2): 3
Triple bottom line impact (3): 2
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 4
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 3
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 3
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 3"
,Rental Hotspots Ltd,"Overall evaluation: 1
Invite to interview: 1
```

What I want to do is grab the numbers after the delimiter `:`, they will always be 1-4.

The ideal output is something like:

```
Snap Election,3,4,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4...
```

and so on, for each organization in the data.

How do get that?

Comment: Did you check the output from `string.split(":")`?

Comment: yeah it just removes `:` and prints the words and then the numbers. are you saying that maybe `array[`X`]` would have it?

Comment: `split` returns a list which maybe empty, if it's not empty then you can index the list, this hint should be enough to help you

Comment: so you mean, change it to `print(word[1])`?

Comment: you mean `print(array[1])`, you won't need the `for` loop after the split

Comment: @S.Matthew_English I fixed a bug in the accepted answer

Comment: @sevenforce thank for alerting me. for curiositys sake, what was the bug?

Comment: Instead of `score 2` in fact `score 1` was printed again. You can see the diff of the edit yourself btw.

Comment: ah, good to know that. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from __future__ import print_function

import csv

with open('comp.csv', 'r') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)
    scores_start_idx = 2

    for row in csv_input:
        organization_name = row[1]
        organization_scores = row[scores_start_idx:]

        for score_idx, score_text in enumerate(organization_scores):
            print(organization_name + ',' + header[score_idx + scores_start_idx], end='')

            for line in score_text.splitlines():
                score = line.split(':')[-1].strip()
                print(',' + score, end='')
            print()
```

returns:

```
Snap Election,Score 1,3,3,4,4,3,4,4,4,3,4,3,4,4,3,4,3,4,3,2,1,4,4
Snap Election,Score 2,3,3,4,4,3,4,4,4,3,4,3,4,4,3,4,3,4,3,2,1,4,4
Rental Hotspots Ltd,Score 1,1 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `left, sep, right = str.partition(":")`
Then you can print `right` if it is not `None`.

Answer (score 1):

The following should get what you need:

```
import csv

with open('comp.csv', 'r') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        counts = [line.split(':')[1].strip() for line in row[2].splitlines()]
        print "{},{}".format(row[1], ",".join(counts))
```

This displays the following:

```
Snap Election,3,3,4,4,3,4,4,4,3,4,3,4,4,3,4,3,4,3,2,1,4,4
Rental Hotspots Ltd,1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Split function in python will split string by delimitor into array.
So, each row you will get array of 2 member 
array[0] = 'text before :'
array[1] = 'text after :'

all you need is remove for word in array: line and change print(word) to print(array[1]) and change some mistake lines

```
import csv

f = open('comp.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f: 
    array = row.split(":")
    print(array[1] + ",")

f.close()
```

Comment: whats the difference between this one and @MartinEvans?

Comment: I split the line then print to screen immediately(line by line), But may be he split all line in to 'counts' array then print out by join all string in array dilimit by ',' at the last line.